# Getting a type error while trying to build a logistic model

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to create a Logistic Regression model with scikit-learn based off a clinical database I have, but I am getting a TypeError, and nothing I do seems to fix it.
I am getting this error:

`TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'`

Thanks for the help in advance!

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

import numpy as np
import csv

target = []
data = []

with open('TABAK_SCORE_BINS.csv', 'r')as f:
```

This file contains a bunch of medical records.  Basically rather they 'A' survived, or 'E' died, with a lot of different clinical variables.

```
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
next(reader, None)
for line in reader:
    if(line[1] == 'A'):
```

line[1] contains the 'A' or 'E' which tells us if the patient survived or not

```
target.append(0)
if(line[1] == 'E'):
    target.append(1)
```

Lines[55:] are all of the variables which I care about, and they are all 1s or 0s

```
data.append(line[55:])

data_arr = np.asarray(data)
```

Splitting the model

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, target, train_size=0.7, random_state=0)
log_reg = LogisticRegression()
log_reg.fit(x_train, y_train)

print(data_arr.shape)
print(data_arr.dtype)
```

The shape is outputted as (295359, 105)
and the dtype is (less than sign)U1

All the code compiles up until this point when I try to predict with the trained model.

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    print(log_reg.predict(data_arr[i].reshape(1, -1)))
```

Comment: can you upload your data `TABAK_SCORE_BINS.csv` ?

Comment: HI seralouk.  I am actually not allowed to upload any data, but I was able to solve the problem.  The values were being stored as strings instead of as ints.  Thanks!